# C# Passing a property from one csproj to another

Tags: c#, unit-testing, msbuild, csproj, rider

So I have some files I'd like to exclude from the compile when running tests, but they're needed at other times.

So I was hoping I could set a property in the test csproj and pass it into the main csproj when running tests. The main csproj would conditionally remove the files.

This is what i've tried with no luck so far:

projectTest.csproj

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="path_to_main_project.csproj">
        <IsRunningTests>true</IsRunningTests>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
...
```

projectMain.csproj

```
...
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(IsRunningTests)' == 'true'">
    <Compile Remove="*ExcludeMe.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

If I set true in the PropertyGroup of the main project, it works. However that's not exactly how I wanna go about it. Tried other various ways but nothing seems to snap into place for it.

EDIT:

Well seems I was a bit misguided in the way I wanted to achieve this. What I ended up doing was adding a run configuration for my main project and keying off of that.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'DebugWithTests'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TEST_BUILD</DefineConstants>
    <IsRunningTests>true</IsRunningTests>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then I could conditionally exclude the needed files like I mentioned above. Leaving the test project untouched.

Comment: This is what `#if` is for. See [preprocessor directives - conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation).

Comment: `IsRunningTests` is metadata you have added to the `path_to_main_project.csproj` item of `@(ProjectReference)`. It is not passing a property to the referenced project. Further, a `ProjectReference` doesn't rebuild a project.

Comment: That sounds backwards, dependencies only work the other way around. Your main project can't know anything about your test project. Though you could define a "Test" and "Debug" configuration for your entire solution, so that your main project has 2 possible outputs. I have to ask "why?". What actual problem are you trying to solve here? Why do you need more code in a release build, that you aren't going to test at all?

Comment: The why of it is because I've hit some sort of limit and the builds keep stalling. I've noticed that removing the migrations files seems to cut the local build times in half and keeps the the builds from stalling locally. 

So was hoping to find some way of selectively ignoring those files during compile, but only when running tests.

Comment: Configurations will get you better results if you build from a solution - you might get weird results when a solution build and a project based build overwrite each other. Plus VS also has up-to-date check handling which will not pick up that dependency.